# Changed PHP handler to DSO - weird custom fields problem

Tags: custom-field

I have a problem for my website.

The homepage lists articles (external links) that are put in categories and that also mention the article source (website where the article is published). These sources are custom fields that I fill on the wordpress post editor.

The problem is that every article shows now the same source, while I have mentionned a different source for each article.

Weird stuff have been happening since I changed my PHP handler to DSO. The problem happened after I changed the handler, so I have high doubts that this might be related.

Do you see a workaround to this please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://halfelf.org/2011/wordpress-dso-and-permissions/ so see if it helps you out.

Basically you need to do the following changes:

On **wp-config.php**:

```
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', (0755 & ~ umask()));
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', (0644 & ~ umask()));
```

To override file permissions.

Then if you got your files with 777 permissions you can change them back easily by doing in console:

```
find /home/foobar/public_html/wp-content/uploads -type d -perm 777 -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find /home/foobar/public_html/wp-content/themes -type d -perm 777 -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find /home/foobar/public_html/wp-content/plugins -type d -perm 777 -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Change **foobar** with your user

Same for files:

```
find /home/foobar/public_html/wp-content/uploads -type f -perm 777 -print -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

And the last thing to do is change the owner to nobody:nobody (user:group) on the folders uploads and upgrade. You can do it like this:

```
chown -R nobody:nobody /home/foobar/public_html/wp-content/uploads/
```

Comment: No problem. Please marks answer as correct if it helped you out

Comment: @chifliiiii Link only answers are not a good format for the community. If the link becomes unavailable, then future users are not able to identify the solution. Would you mind updating your answer to tell everyone specifically how this link answers the question?

Comment: @BrianFegter fair enough :D

Comment: @chifliiiii Nice work :)